# How to get total width and height of page considering scrolling

Tags: javascript

I want to know how to get page`s total height and width considering its scrolling.
right now I am using

```
height1= screen.availHeight;
width1=screen.availWidth;
```

but when page scroll it  is not useful.. is there another way in JavaScript?

Comment: yeah I saw that.  So you read the Question title that I comment?? ` How to get document height and width **without using jquery**`

Comment: getting height and width without jquery like this
height = document.body.clientHeight;
width = document.body.clientWidth;

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```
var body = document.body;
var height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight);
var width= Math.max( body.scrollWidth, body.offsetWidth);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get height and width try this

this is for full HTML page using jquery

```
$(document).height();
$(document).width();
```

and this is for only window

```
$(window).height();
$(window).width();
```

Answer (score 0):

Returns height of browser viewport

```
$(window).height();
```

Returns height of HTML document

```
$(document).height();
```